# Existence of linear combinations in $\mathbb{R}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

We know that $a\in\mathbb{R}$ is a root of $f(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x]$ if and only if $f(x)=(x-a)g(x)$ for some $g\in\mathbb{R}[x]$.

Now let's say $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ and $f(a_1,\dots,a_n)=0$. Then can we say that there exists $g_i(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ such that $f=\sum\limits^n_{i=1}(x_i-a_i)g_i$? If so, how do I prove it (since we cannot apply division algorithm to UFDs)? If not, are there a easy counterexample?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, this is true and straightforward to prove. By translating $f$ appropriately you can assume WLOG that $a_1 = a_2 = \dots = a_n = 0$. Now just look at the terms of $f$.

Comment: You can just use the fact that R[x, y] = R[x][y] and apply the first part